# Saving node with a text format another user doesn't have permission for renders it inaccessible

Tags: users, wysiwyg, input-formats

I have an editor role which has access to an editor Text format.
I have an admin role which uses the Full HTML format.

When the admin edits a node and saves the body (or any other full text field) with their default text format, Full HTML, then the editor gets:

"This field has been disabled because you do not have sufficient permissions to edit it."

How can I allow the editors to simply have permission to edit this locked field with their own editor text format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't I'm afraid.

Think about it like this: When rendering the text to screen, Drupal has to decide which text format to use to filter it. This means that per field, there must only be one text format, regardless of which users have edited it.

If this wasn't the case, Drupal would have no idea which format to use to render the text. It would have to guess, which is something you don't want a computer doing!

If you want users to be able to edit textarea fields, your admins will simply have to save them in a format that those users have permissions to use. Otherwise the whole point of having different filters available for different roles is kind of lost.

But the main point is that conceptually, if different users edit the same field, with different text formats, then Drupal has no idea which one to use when outputting the field value. This is why you cannot do it.

Comment: That makes sense, glad to just have a definitive answer. Thanks.

Comment: This problem could be solved if Drupal would simply save the field in the new text format, and forget the old format. E.g. user A saves as "Full HTML", user says "break text format" and saves as "Filtered HTML". Maybe an additional affirmative action would be required, because user B cannot undo this.

Comment: And there could be a permission "break text formats".

Comment: Maybe that's an idea for a new contrib module.

Answer (score 0):

Now 10 years later, there is also https://www.drupal.org/project/allowed_formats, which allows to limit text formats for a field to those, that everybody can use.