# Possible to fallback to a simple text format

Tags: 9, wysiwyg

We have to Textformats for the WYSIWYG editor:

- full html (intended for admins with html knowledge)
- simple html (for the non-tech editors)

Both can edit the node

However, if the admin save a field with full html, it is automatically blocked for the normal editors, as they have no permission for the "full html":

[image]

Is there a way, that the field is simply using "simple html" as fallback? It would be no problem if the markup got sanitised more then it would be with full html...

I found [this old post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27594/saving-node-with-a-text-format-another-user-doesnt-have-permission-for-renders) from 10 years ago - maybe something has changed in the meantime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, so I found the well maintained module [allowed_formats](https://www.drupal.org/project/allowed_formats).

This actually solves my problem, as I can limit the format to simple html for those few fields, that the normal editors have access too.